# Get directory of file c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a file manager class, and the class has a property called "dir" that holds the directory of an opened file.

So, take the following code for example

```
File f("test.txt");
```

Then `f.dir = "C:\...\current_directory\test.txt";` and I achieve this just append the working directory to the beginning of the string given. However usimg this approach take this example

```
File f("C:\...\Desktop\cool.txt");
```

Here `f.dir = "C:\...\current_directory\C:\...\Desktop\test.txt";`

So, if they give a direct address, and I prepped the working directory, this would be wrong.

So the question is this, how can I determine if they sent an absolute address or an indirect one?

Comment: test if the name of file contains \ you will know that they give a file name, you could add your path , if it contains \ than it's a direct address

Comment: "\c" is the same as "c".  Make sure to use "c:\\...\\Desktop\\cool.txt", or this will bite you on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not find a colon, ':' anywhere in the path except after the drive letter. If it is absolute, look at character 2.

You will also have to look for paths prefixed with "\\" to get UNC paths.

And watch out for how you're getting the working directory. The obvious argv[0] does not always hold.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question, but this may help you. I don't know what is the purpose of your work (playing around with some code, academic, enterprise, etc) and I don't know what restrictions you may have. But take in consideration [Boost C++ libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/index.html) and [Boost FileSystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), which makes this task very easy.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated it's probably best to find an external library that does this; however, that being said, it looks like you are working on Windows. There is a Windows API call that resolves relative paths to full paths and keeps full paths: `GetFullPathName` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx)).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    DWORD ret;
    char buf[1024];
    ret = GetFullPathName("test.cpp", 1024, buf, NULL);
    if (ret) printf("%s\n", buf);
    ret = GetFullPathName("C:\\path\\to\\test.cpp", 1024, buf, NULL);
    if (ret) printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directories do not exist in standard C++11 (and a C++11 conforming implementation can exist without any directories). Future C++ standards might have something related to file systems, e.g. [`<experimental/filesystem>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/filesystem) header.

POSIX has [realpath](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/realpath.html) and [dirname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirname.html).

Probably your Windows operating system has some OS specific API, perhaps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You might use [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or [Boost](http://boost.org/). All provide some API wrapping directories and file systems.

AFAIK the notion of current directory is OS specific and is different in Windows and in POSIX (which has *the* current *working* directory of a process, with [getcwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html)). IIRC MS-DOS (so probably Windows) had a current directory on each drive.

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP's question?

Comment: He's just saying that there are better alternatives and that OP don't need to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: `realpath` is for chasing symlinks and normalizing `foo/../bar` kinds of things.  POSIX `dirname(3)` does what the OP wants (with nasty semantics: might modify the input string, or might return a pointer to a static buffer).  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirname.html